# Laravel IoC bindings with multiple use cases

Tags: php, laravel, model-view-controller, dependency-injection, interface

We have two types of repositories in our application:

- `App\Repositories\Database\PostRepository`
- `App\Repositories\ElasticSearch\PostRepository`

They both implement the same contract `PostRepositoryInterface`.

**My question is:**

Mostly we will use `Database\PostRepository` to retrieve our entities, although we want to use `ElasticSearch\PostRepository` in certain cases:

- When we return large collections
- When searching via full-text-queries

How can we get around our default service binding: `PostRepositoryInterface >> Database\PostRepository`, in the cases we want to actually use our ElasticSearch repositories?

I have the feeling depending directly on our concrete `ElasticSearch\PostRepository` implementation is not a great idea.

Comment: check out providers and IoC documentation on laravel. You can switch binding on runtime.

Comment: Sure, although it's not so much switching at runtime. Rather it's always being called in that location

Comment: For example we ALWAYS want to use it in some CONTROLLERS and other classes

Answer (score 0):

Repository Based Abstraction can help you if you are using different apps with different case, you want to have some models to be called from one DB and other for other.

Because you can not switch repository at runtime, you need to switch model.

Consider you have one repository.

```
// YOUR REPO FILE
use App\Models\ElasticPostModel;
use App\Models\DatabasePostModel;
PostRepository extends SomeRepo implements SomeInterface{
    public function __construct(<Inject Both Models>){
        $this->databaseModel = $databaseModel;
        $this->elasticModel = $elasticModel;

        // You may want to set default model here;
        $this->model = $databaseModel;
    }

    public function switch($type = 'database'){
        if($type == 'elastice')
            $this->model = $this->elasticModel;
        else
            $this->model = $this->databaseModel;
    }

}

// SPECIFY CONNECTION IN ELASTIC MODEL
ElasticPostModel extends Model{
    protected $connection = 'elastic';
}

// ADD CONNECTION DETAILS IN config/db.php

'elastic' => [
    'driver' => 'elastic'
]
```

This way when you need to switch database call **switch** method before query. Eloquent will write query based on connection, if ORM supports it.